# Valor inputado não aparece

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, pascal

Estou com uma dúvida em um exercício em que eu tenho que mostrar qual número é o menor ou o maior inputado.

Porém não está trazendo o resultado correto.

```
Segue o código.
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lblN1: TLabel;
    lblN2: TLabel;
    edtN1: TEdit;
    edtN2: TEdit;
    btnMostrar: TButton;
    procedure btnMostrarClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnMostrarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  edtN1 : Integer;
  edtN2: Integer;

begin

    if edtN1.Size > edtN2.Size then
      ShowMessage('O número 1 é o maior!')
    else
      ShowMessage('O número 2 é o maior!');
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está a usar a propriede Size.... que nao lhe diz nada sobre o que foi digitado.
Precisa usar o

```
if StrToInt(edtN1.Text)> StrToInt(edtN2.Text) then
```

Comment: Percebi que o edt sempre recebe string, então logo tem que converter. Obrigado porém deu outro erro "integer does not containt a member named  'Text'

Comment: @MatheusLima o erro apresentado `integer does not containt a member named 'Text` é exatamente o que respondi.

Comment: Matheus sou capaz de apostar que pôs um ')' num sitio errado :D Esse código que aí pus tem de compilar...
De certeza que nao pos StrToInt(edtN1).Text em vez de StrToInt(edtN1.Text)?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos ao problema em si. O Teste lógico esta errado, pois existe duas variáveis com o mesmo nome dos componentes.

E no pascal ele vai dar prioridade para as variáveis locais.

Você não recebeu erro de compilação porque `Integer` possui uma função chamada `Size`.

O correto seria testar conforme já respondido: `if StrToInt(edtN1.Text)> StrToInt(edtN2.Text) then`

ou

```
edtN1 := StrToInt(edtN1.Text);
edtN2 := StrToInt(edtN2.Text);

if edtN1 > edtN2 then
...
```